# Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I am writing a simple custom annotation in Java and running into a problem with it. Here is the main parts of my code.

**LogMeCustomAnnotation.java**

```
package fun.n.learn.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

// We need this annotation only till before compilation.
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
// This is a simple custom annotation.
public @interface LogMeCustomAnnotation {

}
```

**LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor.java**

```
package fun.n.learn.annotation;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Messager;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

// List the custom annotations that are supported.
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ "fun.n.learn.annotation.LogMeCustomAnnotation" })
// Extend AbstractProcessor. This will let you process.
public class LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "I was here.");

        // TODO: Put some meaningful code here. Right now just get it to work.

        // return false;
        // We have already handled these annotations. No more. So return true.
        return true;
    }

}
```

**/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
fun.n.learn.annotation.LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fun.n.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaCustomAnnotation</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Configure the project to use java 8 version. -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves. -->
                    <!-- <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Now when I run `mvn -e clean install` I get the following problem

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider fun.n.learn.annotation.LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor not found
[INFO] 1 error
```

I must be missing a simple trick here. Any help?

Answer (score 32):

The default maven lifecycle runs javac with **javax.annotation.processing.Processor** file as a part of classpath. This cause compiler to expect a compiled instance of annotation processors listed in the files. But `LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor` is not compiled at that moment so compiler raises "Bad service configuration file ..." error. See [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-97). 


To solve this issue maven compilation phase can be separated to compile annotation processor at the first place and then compile whole project.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                        <includes>
                            <include>fun/n/learn/annotation/LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor.java</include>
                            <!--include dependencies required for LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor -->
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-project</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`default-compile` execution compiles `LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor` with disabled annotation processing in order to have successful compilation.

`compile-project` compiles whole project with annotaton processing.

Comment: How do I run a particular type of execution?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce execution-id specification is available since Maven 3.3.1  [MNG-5768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768). `mvn compiler:compile@compile-project`

Comment: `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` means disabling annotation processing, its bad idea. You are moving away from the actual problem to compile the `LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor `.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad - please read answer carefully. Compilation is split in two steps. At first step `LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor` is compiled and obviously here we don't need annotation processing to be enabled. Second step compiles whole project with enabled annotation processing.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back from the grave but What to do if I am using another annotation processor like Lambok

Answer (score 5):

Ok. Found the issue. Earlier my pom.xml had the `proc:none` line commented out. Now that I have got it back in action it is compiling fine. I need to find out exactly what this line does, but the answer to my question is just put the `proc:none` back in game. This is how the build section of my pom.xml looks now.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Configure the project to use java 8 version. -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <!-- Disable annotation processing for ourselves. -->
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` disables annotation processing. So `LogMeCustomAnnotation ` will never be processd. Probably it is not what you expected in your original question.

Comment: Fixed mine too!

Answer (score 3):

Follow the following steps to resolve this:

- Edit `nbproject/project.properties` file
- Search for `javac.processorpath`, and change it to:

`javac.processorpath=\
              ${javac.classpath}:\
              ${libs.eclipselink.classpath}`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error, in particular

```
Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.iviz.schemarestriction.processor.SchemaRestrictionCompilationProcessor could not be instantiated
```

when migrating maven project from JDK 1.8 (1.8.0_201) to OpenJDK 11(11.0.2).

It was fixed by adding dependency on (2.3.1 was the latest stable version)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the following issue just by deleting the Target folder of annotation-processor and compiled the framework again. It worked like a magic.

Issue:

`java: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider com.tracelink.automation.framework.processors.FeedFactoryProcessor not found`

Comment: You say "you have resolved and it worked" but you are posting another issue. It's a new issue you are getting ?

Answer (score -1):

try compiling it with the flag: `-proc:none`