# Compilation failure error given when doing Maven Install in IntelliJ with JavaFX and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

My code is able to be run and works perfectly, but when I try to make a fat jar with Maven Install, it gives the error:

```
Compilation failure
Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: com.google.auto.service.processor.AutoServiceProcessor Unable to get public no-arg constructor
```

I'm not sure what's causing it, maybe Selenium? I was able to get mvn install to work when I had the default JavaFX project, but once I ported in my code for Data Storage, Selenium, and my custom GUI it stopped working.

Heres my project structure:

[image]

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PleaseWork</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PleaseWork</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.pleasework.Main_1</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <includes>
                                <include>fun/n/learn/annotation/LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor.java</include>
                                <!--include dependencies required for LogMeCustomAnnotationProcessor -->
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.pleasework.Main_1</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have 2 mains, Main_1 does not extend Application and is being used to run Main

Comment: You already have a jlink config and a module info file. It might be better for you to use the openjfx plugin to create a jlink based runtime image or use jpackage rather than  trying to create an unsupported maven shade fat jar. If you do use jlink, check that the module info is requiring all of the modules you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @jewelsea said, it was a duplicate of [Can't compile my javafx and selenium project due to google autoservice processor ("Unable to get public no-arg constructor")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679962/cant-compile-my-javafx-and-selenium-project-due-to-google-autoservice-processor).

Once I changed

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

to this

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
                            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Everything worked!